# Tell regex to not do what it's supposed to. (Don't replace $&)

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium, nightwatch.js

So I have a preprocessor for testing that replaces comments to build up automated tests in a DRY way. It generates files that can then be ran normally. The only problems show up when I need to use regexp INSIDE the test step, like this:

```
.step(/^Search for special characters$/, function() {
    client.setValue("input[type=text]", "@#$%^&*()_ -={}[]|\\\"':;? >.<,`©®ÉÖ]]™\"".replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|"'#\s]/g, "\\$&")
}
```

So of course what I end up with is a test file that looks like this:

```
client.setValue("input[type=text]", "@#$%^&*()_ -={}[]|\\\"':;? >.<,`©®ÉÖ]]™\"".replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|"'#\s]/g, "\\//Search for special characters")
```

Is there anyway to tell javascript "DON'T replace $& with the match result!"?

Comment: Could you provide desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the whole workflow, `$$` seems to work:

```js
txt = '123';

step = function(re, fn) {
  return txt.replace(re, fn.toString());
}

code = step(/^123$/, function() {
    return "abc".replace(/./g, "$$&")
});
  
document.write(code);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(eval("(" + code + ")()"));
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. :)

Comment: He beat you to it, but yours came up on the top of my notifications haha. Marking this one as correct because of the code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

The `.replace()` function substitutes (interploates) things that begin with `$`. So `$` is the character that you need to escape, since backslashes are still the escape mechanism for the JS string itself.

This works by doubling it:

```
"foo".replace(/foo/, "$$&")
```

Also see: [The spec, section 15.5.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11).

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly the output I needed. I didn't know about doubling the $. This is exactly what I needed. Now I'll just need to procedurally add the second $ in, because other people will be using this and I don't expect them to know the same.

Comment: This applies to outputting `"$1"` as well. Normally `$1` would be interpolated with the contents of group 1, but `$$1` would appear as `"$1"`  in the output.